# In which folder to run this PowerShell script?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, bamboo

I am following the [example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx). It is publishing an ASP.NET application to a docker container on a remote Linux sever.

There is a small piece of work to run script.
Let's quote it.

> Also be sure to explore the PublishProfiles folder that gets created
>   in your Visual Studio project under "Properties." A PowerShell script
>   and a Shell script get created in that folder that you can use to
>   publish your app from the command line. For example:

```
.\hanseldocker-Docker-publish.ps1 -packOutput $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp -pubxmlFile .\hanseldocker-Docker.pubxml
```

I am not sure the location of `.\`. Actually I am using [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) to build it, I have to place the script into the body.

[image].

I don't know whether I should modify the script because of `.\`?

Comment: .\ just means the current directory you are working in. You need to tell Bamboo where your PS script is located. You can also pick "File" instead of "Inline" in "Script Location". Now you can point directly to the powershell script and input the arguments / env. variables as needed.

Comment: @Gunnar, I am not sure how to put the arguments there. Would you please give me a snapshot? In my case, I have `-packOutput $env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp -pubxmlFile .\CustomDockerProfile.pubxml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a solution at [here.](http://geekrandomnotes.blogspot.com/2011/11/powershell-and-bamboo.html)

To launch it using the regular old, command line and pass any powershell script as a parameters.

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "echo Hesus | C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe %*"
```

Put this in the Argument:

```
scripts\RemoteWSPDeployment.ps1 –parameter1 value1 –parameter2 value2
```